# mac OS finder sorting

Tags: finder

So, theoretically, mac OS finder uses natural sort. I thought "great, easy to replicate".
But then, in a given folder with anonymized names for images, sorted by name, this order happened:

- 4445848355278617937001.jpg
- 4445848355278617937002.jpg
- 6401371244885357529001.jpg
- 6401371244885357529002.jpg
- 6401371244885357529003.jpg
- 6401371244885357529004.jpg
- 8467449627832563381001.jpg
- 8467449627832563381002.jpg
- 8467449627832563381003.jpg
- 8467449627832563381004.jpg
- 1679313641425563047001.jpg        <--- what's giving me trouble
- 1679313641425563047002.jpg
- 1679313641425563047003.jpg
- 1679313641425563047004.jpg
- ...

See, I don't understand why it places 1679313641425563047001 after all of the previous filenames. I checked, it's a smaller number, so natural sort should NOT do this. Can someone explain what the hell mac's finder is doing here? I only pasted the initial part of the folder, but it does this all over the place. Is it possibly a bug for large numbers in finder?

Comment: This is not a programming problem, and *finder* hardly is a *tool prominently used in programming*: Check ["power" user](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) and [Which computer science/programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on)

Comment: as per your own link, it covers a software algorithm, natural sort, used in finder (which is so frequent in this site it even has its own tag, with 760 questions), and a specific bug in that software algorithm implementation likely related to big numbers. When testing with numbers that fit within uint64_t (8 bytes), no ordering issue is found, but for these numbers, the order seems completely off.

Comment: *finder* not exactly being open source, there are several routes of action: 0) Describe what you want done. 1) Ask (yourself, if still necessary: others) how to get it done - a) using existing tools (possibly after a bug report&fix) (I keep forgetting [U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic%5D)) b) with a new tool to be created (a language handling numbers without artificial limits would seem handy).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Added dots to split the image names adding a dot every 3 digits, order is now as expected.